# How to generate getters for lombok Builder?

Tags: java, lombok, getter, builder

I have the following definition:

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class MyEntity {
  String name;
}
```

When trying to use a getter on a builder, e.g. `MyEntityBuilder.getName()`, IDEA states that it "Cannot resolve method". Also, IDEA doesn't auto-complete it.

The only available method (except `build()`) is the setter: `MyEntityBuilder name(String name);`

Is there a way to generate getter on lombok generated builders? Thanks.

Using Lombok `1.8.16`.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be no option to do it out of the box according to the [Lombok docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) or the [source code](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/Builder.java).

If you want to inspect the contents of the builder, the best you can do, it seems, is to build the object and inspect the field from there.

Comment: This is unfortunate. I prefer `builder.expensiveValue(compute())`, then using that value. It keeps code concise, don't have to declare or pass a ton of intermediate variables. Often, calling `.build()` causes exceptions because validation.

Answer (score 1):

Builders do not,
generally,
have getters.
The builder pattern is this:

1. Create the builder.
2. Set values in the builder.
3. Call build().

Answer (score 1):

As [answer from DwB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69827795/6413377) suggests builder pattern does not need nor use getters.

You can have a getter for Lombok builder values but I think that it would not be very useful. You can customize builder this way:

```
@Value
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class MyEntity {
    String name;
    String name2; // just something to set also
    // Customized builder
    public static class MyEntityBuilder {
        private String name;
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        // This is not actually needed but just as an example howto
        // customise a setter.
        public MyEntityBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And to test it (Junit5):

```
@Test
void test() {
    MyEntityBuilder meb = MyEntity.builder(); 
    var myEntity = meb
            // You need to set this first to access it later
            .name("Name #1")
            // The benefit having a getter ?
            .name2(meb.getName())
            .build();
    assertEquals(myEntity.getName(), myEntity.getName2());
}
```

Comment: "builder pattern does not need nor use getters" Plenty of cases where you might use a getter, for example passing a builder with a collection member through several layers, each which adds to the collection.

Comment: @AdrianBaker I did not say that it can not use. It just does not need and does not use by default. As in my answer Lombok does not generate getters for builder unless implemented self. It is also possible pass the builder itself before build and if needed also make customized method for some collection to add items. For lombok see [this](https://www.projectlombok.org/features/Builder) and howto use *@Singular*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have a getter for a builder (but not generated).

We can just create an inner Builder class and add a getter method. That's it!

Example:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Value
public class Yes {
    String fieldA;

    String fieldB;

    public static class YesBuilder {
        public String getFieldA() {
            return fieldA;
        }

        // Can do the same with fieldB but can also keep it without getter.
    }
}
```

Execution example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Yes.YesBuilder builder = Yes.builder();
    builder.fieldA("Yes A");
    builder.fieldB("Yes B");
    // System.out.println(builder.fieldA); - compile error
    System.out.println(builder.getFieldA());
    // System.out.println(builder.getFieldB()); - compile error
    System.out.println(builder.build());
}
```

Res:

```
Yes A
Yes(fieldA=Yes A, fieldB=Yes B)
```

Answer (score -3):

You mentioned you were using IntelliJ IDEA as your IDE. It so happens that there is an IDEA plugin exactly for this:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

Once the plugin is installed, IDEA should recognize Lombok's annotation syntax.

Comment: The syntax is recognized. I can see a setter but not a getter.